# Trying to scrape multiple urls from a csv file. But facing response 404 for all urls except last url which loads from csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, httpresponse

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import lxml
with open('xyz/spec.csv') as file:
    reqdata = []
    for line in file:
        headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
        r = requests.get(line, headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
        need = soup.find_all('span', attrs={"class":"10965hju"})
        needs = []
        for tit in need:
            needs.append(tit.text.strip())
        reqdata.append(needs)
        
    print(reqdata)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are just reading lines from a csv file all of your urls have a linebreak character (`\n`) at the end, except for the last one.

The simplest solution for this would be

`r = requests.get(line.strip(), headers=headers)`

[strip](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) with no arguments removes leading and trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

See below

(You will have to share `spec.csv` if you are still facing issues)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('xyz/spec.csv') as file:
    reqdata = []
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
    for line in [l.strip() for l in file.readlines()]:
        r = requests.get(line, headers=headers)
        if r.status_code == 200:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
            need = soup.find_all('span', attrs={"class": "10965hju"})
            needs = []
            for tit in need:
                needs.append(tit.text.strip())
            reqdata.append(needs)

print(reqdata)
```